# Deploying Maven Java application to OpenShift on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, git, maven, tomcat, openshift

I have a Java application built with Maven running on my local PC.  I'm using Eclipse and Apache/Tomcat for my server.  I have two projects in my application:

1. The Java code (JavaApp)
2. The Web Application (WebApp)

In my WebApp Pom I am including my JavaApp as a dependency.  This runs fine on my local server with Eclipse & Apache/Tomcat.

I have an OpenShift account and have created an Application/Cartridge for Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0).  Using Git I was followed the instructions and;

1. Created a clone of the OpenShift app on my local Git.
2. I deleted the SRC directory and pom.xml file from the local clone.
3. Using Maven I created a WAR file from my WebApp project.  I verified by looking in to the WAR file that my JavaApp is included in the WEB-INF/lib as a jar file.
4. I copied my WAR file in to the clone's webapps directory.
5. I issued the git add . to update my new files.
6. I issued the git commit -m "updated war file" command to commit the changes
7. I issued the git push command to push my application to OpenShift.

My cmd window reports the push is a success.  I then go to my application URL and I'm getting jsp errors.  The way my application is configured, it goes to a servlet first before being directed to the index.jsp.  I've attached an object to the page to populate some fields.  The errors are saying that the JSP can't find any of the methods of my object.  This application is working fine on my local server.  I suspect that for some reason the OpenShift deployment of my WebApp can't find my Java code (please see below).

I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this error, any help would be appreciated!

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
The method getLastLocationSearched() is undefined for the type WelcomePageBean

5: <head>
6: <%@ page import ="org.williards.core.client.beans.WelcomePageBean" %>
7: <% WelcomePageBean pageBean = (WelcomePageBean)   request.getAttribute("pageBean"); %>
8: <% if(pageBean.getLastLocationSearched() != null){ %>
9:  <script>
10:         var lastSearchLocation = <%= pageBean.getLastLocationSearched() %>;
11:     </script>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.williards.core.servlets.WelcomeServlet.pageNavigation(WelcomeServlet.java:26)
    org.williards.core.servlets.AbstractServlet.doGet(AbstractServlet.java:49)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Answer (score 0):

my first question would be whether your war (I mean the war as deployed to OpenShift, not the source) works locally? I suspect that your war does not contain all dependencies.
To work properly in OpenShift you need to make sure OpenShift has all the dependencies. 
When deploying as a war you can add 3rd party jars into

`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`

The other option is to deploy via source which allows you to indicate dependencies via pom.

You can see all the details in the following OpenShift kb article:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-dependencies.html